# Backpack for laravel - Error updating rows

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

I'm trying to update rows of some tables on my admin. It's running with backpack crud. I've doing some debug and I'm ending on this sentence in backpack CrudController (vendor/backpack/crud/src/app/http/controllers/crudController - UpdateCrud function).

```
$request->get($this->crud->model->getKeyName();
```

It's giving me a null value when I use dd() on it. So the final result shows me a 404 Error saying 'No query results for model ['Model route']'. Also I print the update request and every field it's ok, sending data without problems.

I spend 6 days trying to resolve this problem and can't find it. This is part of my code, thanks for your time.

Controller (I resume some fields, because are to many)

```
class OperadoresCrudController extends CrudController {
  public function setup(){
    $this->crud->setModel('App\Models\Operador');
    $this->crud->setRoute("admin/operadores");
    $this->crud->setEntityNameStrings('operadores', 'operadores');
    $this->crud->enableExportButtons();

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | BASIC CRUD INFORMATION
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    //$this->crud->setFromDb();

    // ------ CRUD FIELDS
    // $this->crud->addField($options, 'update/create/both');
    // $this->crud->addFields($array_of_arrays, 'update/create/both');
    // $this->crud->removeField('name', 'update/create/both');
    // $this->crud->removeFields($array_of_names, 'update/create/both');

    $this->crud->addField([
      'name'  => 'nombre',
      'label' => 'Nombre *',
      'type'  => 'text',
      'wrapperAttributes' => [
        'class' => 'form-group col-md-7'
      ],
      'tab'  => 'Datos Generales'
    ]);

    $this->crud->addField([
      'name' =>  'rut',
      'label' => 'Rut',
      'type'  => 'text',
      'wrapperAttributes' => [
        'class' => 'form-group col-md-7'
      ],
      'tab'  => 'Datos Generales'
    ]);

    public function store(StoreRequest $request) {
      return parent::storeCrud();
    }

    public function update(UpdateRequest $request) {
      #dd($request);
      return parent::updateCrud();
    }
 }
```

**Model**

```
class Operador extends Model {
  use CrudTrait;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| GLOBAL VARIABLES
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

  protected $table = 'operador';
  //protected $primaryKey = 'id';
  // public $timestamps = false;
  // protected $guarded = ['id'];
  protected $fillable = ['nombre','rut','direccion','telefono','email','comuna_id','url','region_id', 'area_operacion','op_nombre_responsable','op_direccion_responsable','op_telefono_responsable','op_email_responsable','created_at','updated_at'];
  // protected $hidden = [];
  // protected $dates = [];

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| FUNCTIONS
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
  public function equipos() {
   return   $this->hasMany('App\Models\Equipo','operador_id');
  }

  public function comuna() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Comuna');
  }

  //para insertar select region, prov, comuna
  public function region() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Region');
  }

  // Estacion Operador.
  public function estaciones() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Estacion','operador_id');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `EntityCrudController::update()` method you should be able to use `$this->crud->entry` after you call `parent::updateCrud()`. So this should work for you to get the current entry ID:

```

```
public function update(UpdateRequest $request)
{
    $redirect_location = parent::updateCrud();

    dd($this->crud->entry->id);

    return $redirect_location;
}
```

```